# Passing column and data frame argument to my function in lapply()?

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, lapply

I have a function that takes in a dataframe and a column in that dataframe. I want to use lapply() to apply my function on every column in the dataframe, but I'm not sure how to do that. 
I think it should look something like:

```
#dataframe is called kstarter
my_func(df, col) {
 ...
}
lapply(kstarter, arg1=kstarter, arg2=??)
```

But I can't seem to get it to work. How can arg2 reference each column that lapply iterates through? I appreciate your help!

Edit:

The function I want apply to use is:

```
get_col_info <- function(col, df) {
  unique_vals <- df %>% 
    select(col) %>%
    distinct() 
  num_u_vals <- nrow(unique_vals)
  if (is.numeric(df[[col]])) {
    return(list(
      min = min(df[[col]]),
      max = max(df[[col]]),
      mean = mean(df[[col]])
    ))
  } else if ((!is.numeric(df[[col]])) & num_u_vals < 10) {
    return(list(
      n_values = num_u_vals,
      unique_values = unique_vals %>% pull()
    ))
  } else if (!is.numeric(df[[col]]) & num_u_vals >= 10) {
    return(list(
      n_values = num_u_vals,
      sample_values = sample(df[[col]], size=10)
    ))
  }
}
```

`get_col_info` needs to take in the column name and dataframe as parameters. 
I want to create a list that gets the col info for each column in the dataframe using lapply, something like `list <- lapply(kstarter, get_col_info(current_col, kstarter))` but I can't figure out the syntax. Please help!

Comment: "I have a function that takes in a dataframe and a column in that dataframe. I want to use lapply() to apply my function on every column in the dataframe" Your question is not terribly clear, but it appears you should use `lapply` inside your function. The way to apply a function `foo` to all columns of a data.frame `DF` is `lapply(DF, foo)`. This only works if `foo` accepts a vector as input because `lapply` passes the vectors (columns) in `DF` to `foo`. `foo` can of course accept other input (and you can specify that in `lapply`) but the data.frame you iterate over needs to be outside `foo`.

Comment: @Roland How can I specify lapply to make foo accept the dataframe as another input?

Comment: I think you can simply use `lapply(kstarter, get_col_info, df = kstarter)`, but you'd have to change the first block in your function to something like `unique_vals <- unique(df[[col]])`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `lapply` on a dataframe, it automatically loop over the columns. Here is an example using the `iris` dataset, but if you provide us some reproducible example, I could adapt it to your data.

```
lapply(iris, mean)
```

Instead of the function `mean`, you could use your own custom anonymous function like this:

```
lapply(iris, function(column){
  rtn=mean(column, na.rm=T)
  return(rtn)
})
```

Or your built function like this:

```
my_func = function(column){
  rtn=mean(column, na.rm=T)
  return(rtn)
}
lapply(kstarter, myfunc)
```

Also, I'd suggest you look up the `map` function from the `purrr` package, as it gives you better control on the return type. For instance `purrr::map(kstarter, myfunc)` would return a `list`, while `purrr::map_df(kstarter, myfunc)` would return a `data.frame`.

Comment: The method I'm trying to go with is the built function, however, my built function has 2 parameters (the dataframe and the column). I'm not sure how to pass in the column and dataframe using lapply. In your example, you use `lapply(kstarter, myfunc)` but myfunc needs the dataframe as well as the column name. So myfunc would look more like `my_func = function(column, dataframe){`. Any ideas?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you mean by "myfunc needs the dataframe as well as the column name". What happens if you loop through the column names? Can you give an example of your function?

Comment: @StupidWolf I apologize for the ambiguity, I edited my post to include my function

Comment: Ok I see now. I try to answer below